# OS returns error when loaded into VB

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I am trying to develop OS, and think I have something that somewhat works. However, when I assemble it into an .iso file like this:

```
nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin kernel.asm
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
dd if=boot.bin of=os.iso bs=512 count=1
dd if=kernel.bin of=os.iso bs=512 count=1
```

and try to run it as an in Virtual Box, I get the following error message:

```
Failed to open the CD/DVD image /home/logan/Desktop/OS/test.iso.
The medium '/home/logan/Desktop/OS/test.iso' can't be used as the requested device type.
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out what's going on, and if it has anything to do with the code, or if it's a format error, and how I could fix it.

These are the two files I used:

kernel.bin:

```
   mov ax, 0x07C0  ; set up segments
   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax

   mov si, welcome
   call print_string

 mainloop:
   mov si, prompt
   call print_string

   mov di, buffer
   call get_string

   mov si, buffer
   cmp byte [si], 0  ; blank line?
   je mainloop       ; yes, ignore it

   mov si, buffer
   mov di, cmd_hi  ; "hi" command
   call strcmp
   jc .helloworld

   mov si, buffer
   mov di, cmd_help  ; "help" command
   call strcmp
   jc .help

   mov si,badcommand
   call print_string 
   jmp mainloop  

 .helloworld:
   mov si, msg_helloworld
   call print_string

   jmp mainloop

 .help:
   mov si, msg_help
   call print_string

   jmp mainloop

 welcome db 'Welcome to My OS!', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
 msg_helloworld db 'Hello OSDev World!', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
 badcommand db 'Bad command entered.', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
 prompt db '>', 0
 cmd_hi db 'hi', 0
 cmd_help db 'help', 0
 msg_help db 'My OS: Commands: hi, help', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
 buffer times 64 db 0

 ; ================
 ; calls start here
 ; ================

 print_string:
   lodsb        ; grab a byte from SI

   or al, al  ; logical or AL by itself
   jz .done   ; if the result is zero, get out

   mov ah, 0x0E
   int 0x10      ; otherwise, print out the character!

   jmp print_string

 .done:
   ret

 get_string:
   xor cl, cl

 .loop:
   mov ah, 0
   int 0x16   ; wait for keypress

   cmp al, 0x08    ; backspace pressed?
   je .backspace   ; yes, handle it

   cmp al, 0x0D  ; enter pressed?
   je .done      ; yes, we're done

   cmp cl, 0x3F  ; 63 chars inputted?
   je .loop      ; yes, only let in backspace and enter

   mov ah, 0x0E
   int 0x10      ; print out character

   stosb  ; put character in buffer
   inc cl
   jmp .loop

 .backspace:
   cmp cl, 0    ; beginning of string?
   je .loop ; yes, ignore the key

   dec di
   mov byte [di], 0 ; delete character
   dec cl       ; decrement counter as well

   mov ah, 0x0E
   mov al, 0x08
   int 10h      ; backspace on the screen

   mov al, ' '
   int 10h      ; blank character out

   mov al, 0x08
   int 10h      ; backspace again

   jmp .loop    ; go to the main loop

 .done:
   mov al, 0    ; null terminator
   stosb

   mov ah, 0x0E
   mov al, 0x0D
   int 0x10
   mov al, 0x0A
   int 0x10     ; newline

   ret

 strcmp:
 .loop:
   mov al, [si]   ; grab a byte from SI
   mov bl, [di]   ; grab a byte from DI
   cmp al, bl     ; are they equal?
   jne .notequal  ; nope, we're done.

   cmp al, 0  ; are both bytes (they were equal before) null?
   je .done   ; yes, we're done.

   inc di     ; increment DI
   inc si     ; increment SI
   jmp .loop  ; loop!

 .notequal:
   clc  ; not equal, clear the carry flag
   ret

 .done:     
   stc  ; equal, set the carry flag
   ret

;   times 510-($-$$) db 0
   dw 0AA55h ; some BIOSes require this signature
```

boot.bin:

```
; ==================================================================
; The DIOS Boot-Loader
; Copyright (C) 2013 ELEMENTAL Developers -- see doc/LICENSE.TXT
;
; Based on a free boot loader by MikeOS Developers. It scans the FAT12
; floppy for KERNEL.BIN (the ELEMENTAL kernel), loads it and executes it.
; This must grow no larger than 512 bytes (one sector), with the final
; two bytes being the boot signature (AA55h). Note that in FAT12,
; a cluster is the same as a sector: 512 bytes.
; ==================================================================


    BITS 16

    jmp short bootloader_start  ; Jump past disk description section
    nop             ; Pad out before disk description


; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; Disk description table, to make it a valid floppy
; Note: some of these values are hard-coded in the source!
; Values are those used by IBM for 1.44 MB, 3.5" diskette

OEMLabel        db "ELEMENTAL"  ; Disk label
BytesPerSector      dw 512      ; Bytes per sector
SectorsPerCluster   db 1        ; Sectors per cluster
ReservedForBoot     dw 1        ; Reserved sectors for boot record
NumberOfFats        db 2        ; Number of copies of the FAT
RootDirEntries      dw 224      ; Number of entries in root dir
                    ; (224 * 32 = 7168 = 14 sectors to read)
LogicalSectors      dw 2880     ; Number of logical sectors
MediumByte      db 0F0h     ; Medium descriptor byte
SectorsPerFat       dw 9        ; Sectors per FAT
SectorsPerTrack     dw 18       ; Sectors per track (36/cylinder)
Sides           dw 2        ; Number of sides/heads
HiddenSectors       dd 0        ; Number of hidden sectors
LargeSectors        dd 0        ; Number of LBA sectors
DriveNo         dw 0        ; Drive No: 0
Signature       db 41       ; Drive signature: 41 for floppy
VolumeID        dd 00000000h    ; Volume ID: any number
VolumeLabel     db "HELIOS     "; Volume Label: any 11 chars
FileSystem      db "FAT12   "   ; File system type: don't change!


; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; Main bootloader code


bootloader_start:
    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Set up 4K of stack space above buffer
    add ax, 544         ; 8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs (loader)
    cli             ; Disable interrupts while changing stack
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    sti             ; Restore interrupts

    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax

    ; NOTE: A few early BIOSes are reported to improperly set DL

    cmp dl, 0
    je no_change
    mov [bootdev], dl       ; Save boot device number
    mov ah, 8           ; Get drive parameters
    int 13h
    jc fatal_disk_error
    and cx, 3Fh         ; Maximum sector number
    mov [SectorsPerTrack], cx   ; Sector numbers start at 1
    movzx dx, dh            ; Maximum head number
    add dx, 1           ; Head numbers start at 0 - add 1 for total
    mov [Sides], dx

no_change:
    mov eax, 0          ; Needed for some older BIOSes

; Start of root = ReservedForBoot + NumberOfFats * SectorsPerFat = logical 19
; Number of root = RootDirEntries * 32 bytes/entry / 512 bytes/sector = 14
; Start of user data = (start of root) + (number of root) = logical 33

floppy_ok:              ; Ready to read first block of data
    mov ax, 19          ; Root dir starts at logical sector 19
    call l2hts

    mov si, buffer          ; Set ES:BX to point to our buffer (see end of code)
    mov bx, ds
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, si

    mov ah, 2           ; Params for int 13h: read floppy sectors
    mov al, 14          ; And read 14 of them

    pusha               ; Prepare to enter loop


read_root_dir:
    popa                ; In case registers are altered by int 13h
    pusha

    stc             ; A few BIOSes do not set properly on error
    int 13h             ; Read sectors using BIOS

    jnc search_dir          ; If read went OK, skip ahead
    call reset_floppy       ; Otherwise, reset floppy controller and try again
    jnc read_root_dir       ; Floppy reset OK?

    jmp reboot          ; If not, fatal double error


search_dir:
    popa

    mov ax, ds          ; Root dir is now in [buffer]
    mov es, ax          ; Set DI to this info
    mov di, buffer

    mov cx, word [RootDirEntries]   ; Search all (224) entries
    mov ax, 0           ; Searching at offset 0


next_root_entry:
    xchg cx, dx         ; We use CX in the inner loop...

    mov si, kern_filename       ; Start searching for kernel filename
    mov cx, 11
    rep cmpsb
    je found_file_to_load       ; Pointer DI will be at offset 11

    add ax, 32          ; Bump searched entries by 1 (32 bytes per entry)

    mov di, buffer          ; Point to next entry
    add di, ax

    xchg dx, cx         ; Get the original CX back
    loop next_root_entry

    mov si, file_not_found      ; If kernel is not found, bail out
    call print_string
    jmp reboot


found_file_to_load:         ; Fetch cluster and load FAT into RAM
    mov ax, word [es:di+0Fh]    ; Offset 11 + 15 = 26, contains 1st cluster
    mov word [cluster], ax

    mov ax, 1           ; Sector 1 = first sector of first FAT
    call l2hts

    mov di, buffer          ; ES:BX points to our buffer
    mov bx, di

    mov ah, 2           ; int 13h params: read (FAT) sectors
    mov al, 9           ; All 9 sectors of 1st FAT

    pusha               ; Prepare to enter loop


read_fat:
    popa                ; In case registers are altered by int 13h
    pusha

    stc
    int 13h             ; Read sectors using the BIOS

    jnc read_fat_ok         ; If read went OK, skip ahead
    call reset_floppy       ; Otherwise, reset floppy controller and try again
    jnc read_fat            ; Floppy reset OK?


; ******************************************************************
fatal_disk_error:
; ******************************************************************
    mov si, disk_error      ; If not, print error message and reboot
    call print_string
    jmp reboot          ; Fatal double error


read_fat_ok:
    popa

    mov ax, 2000h           ; Segment where we'll load the kernel
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, 0

    mov ah, 2           ; int 13h floppy read params
    mov al, 1

    push ax             ; Save in case we (or int calls) lose it


; Now we must load the FAT from the disk. Here's how we find out where it starts:
; FAT cluster 0 = media descriptor = 0F0h
; FAT cluster 1 = filler cluster = 0FFh
; Cluster start = ((cluster number) - 2) * SectorsPerCluster + (start of user)
;               = (cluster number) + 31


load_file_sector:
    mov ax, word [cluster]      ; Convert sector to logical
    add ax, 31

    call l2hts          ; Make appropriate params for int 13h

    mov ax, 2000h           ; Set buffer past what we've already read
    mov es, ax
    mov bx, word [pointer]

    pop ax              ; Save in case we (or int calls) lose it
    push ax

    stc
    int 13h

    jnc calculate_next_cluster  ; If there's no error...

    call reset_floppy       ; Otherwise, reset floppy and retry
    jmp load_file_sector


    ; In the FAT, cluster values are stored in 12 bits, so we have to
    ; do a bit of maths to work out whether we're dealing with a byte
    ; and 4 bits of the next byte -- or the last 4 bits of one byte
    ; and then the subsequent byte!

calculate_next_cluster:
    mov ax, [cluster]
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 3
    mul bx
    mov bx, 2
    div bx              ; DX = [cluster] mod 2
    mov si, buffer
    add si, ax          ; AX = word in FAT for the 12 bit entry
    mov ax, word [ds:si]

    or dx, dx           ; If DX = 0 [cluster] is even; if DX = 1 then it's odd

    jz even             ; If [cluster] is even, drop last 4 bits of word
                    ; with next cluster; if odd, drop first 4 bits

odd:
    shr ax, 4           ; Shift out first 4 bits (they belong to another entry)
    jmp short next_cluster_cont


even:
    and ax, 0FFFh           ; Mask out final 4 bits


next_cluster_cont:
    mov word [cluster], ax      ; Store cluster

    cmp ax, 0FF8h           ; FF8h = end of file marker in FAT12
    jae end

    add word [pointer], 512     ; Increase buffer pointer 1 sector length
    jmp load_file_sector


end:                    ; We've got the file to load!
    pop ax              ; Clean up the stack (AX was pushed earlier)
    mov dl, byte [bootdev]      ; Provide kernel with boot device info

    jmp 2000h:0000h         ; Jump to entry point of loaded kernel!

; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; BOOTLOADER SUBROUTINES

reboot:
    mov ax, 0
    int 16h             ; Wait for keystroke
    mov ax, 0
    int 19h             ; Reboot the system


print_string:               ; Output string in SI to screen
    pusha

    mov ah, 0Eh         ; int 10h teletype function

.repeat:
    lodsb               ; Get char from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done            ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h             ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp short .repeat

.done:
    popa
    ret


reset_floppy:       ; IN: [bootdev] = boot device; OUT: carry set on error
    push ax
    push dx
    mov ax, 0
    mov dl, byte [bootdev]
    stc
    int 13h
    pop dx
    pop ax
    ret


l2hts:          ; Calculate head, track and sector settings for int 13h
            ; IN: logical sector in AX, OUT: correct registers for int 13h
    push bx
    push ax

    mov bx, ax          ; Save logical sector

    mov dx, 0           ; First the sector
    div word [SectorsPerTrack]
    add dl, 01h         ; Physical sectors start at 1
    mov cl, dl          ; Sectors belong in CL for int 13h
    mov ax, bx

    mov dx, 0           ; Now calculate the head
    div word [SectorsPerTrack]
    mov dx, 0
    div word [Sides]
    mov dh, dl          ; Head/side
    mov ch, al          ; Track

    pop ax
    pop bx

    mov dl, byte [bootdev]      ; Set correct device

    ret


; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; STRINGS AND VARIABLES

    kern_filename   db "KERNEL  BIN"    ; MikeOS kernel filename

    disk_error  db "Floppy error! Press any key...", 0
    file_not_found  db "KERNEL.BIN not found!", 0

    bootdev     db 0    ; Boot device number
    cluster     dw 0    ; Cluster of the file we want to load
    pointer     dw 0    ; Pointer into Buffer, for loading kernel


; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; END OF BOOT SECTOR AND BUFFER START

    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with zeros
    dw 0AA55h       ; Boot signature (DO NOT CHANGE!)


buffer:             ; Disk buffer begins (8k after this, stack starts)


; ==================================================================
```

If it matters I am on Ubuntu, using NASM, and Virtual Box
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't create a valid iso image, presumably that's why virtualbox is refusing to load it.
You can use what you have created as floppy or hard disk image, or create a proper bootable iso using some tool such as `mkisofs`.

From a quick glance, the boot loader expects a FAT file system that you don't create either. You'll either have to change it so it simply loads the second sector, or create a proper FAT file system.

Also note that the second invocation of `dd` will overwrite the output of the first (you can easily see that by checking the size of the file).